# Parsing the String in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to parse the SQL queries(equal, greater, less than, AND operator) in java in form of string. I have a class

```
class QueryBuilder()
{
 Expression parse(String query)
 {
  String[] token = query.split("\\s+");
  String field = token[0];
  String value = token[1];
  String operator = token[2];

  switch (operator)
  case "EQ" (equals):
   return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.EQ, value);
  case "LT" (less than):
   return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.LT, value);
  case "GT" (greater than):
   return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.GT, value);
  default (In condition):
   return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.IN, value);
 }
}
}
```

//  When I call this class:

```
QueryBuilder ob= new QueryBuilder();
ob.parse("eid EQ 2"); ///This will give results with eid =2 records

Similarly ob.parse("eid GT 2"); //This will give results eid>2 records.

Now I want to add Logical Expression like AND:

For Ex: ob.parse("eid EQ 2 AND deptname foo");// it should give both eid=2 AND 

deptname="foo"
```

Can someone please help me how to parse the STRING with AND condition?

Comment: Now you're having two categories of operator. Consider using recursive descent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you're having two categories of operator. Consider using a recursive descent.

You would have the rules:

Expression ::= BinaryExpression ( BooleanOperator BinaryExpression )*

BooleanOperator ::= "OR"|"AND"

BinaryExpression ::= Name BinaryOperator Value

BinaryOperator ::= "EQ"|"LT"|"GT"|"IN"

So here is a very simple implementation:

```
public class QueryBuilder {
    final String[] token;
    int i = 0;

    public static Expression parse(String query) {
        return new QueryBuilder(query).expression();
    }

    private QueryBuilder(String query) {
        token = query.split("\\s+");
    }

    private Expression expression() {
        Expression expr = binaryExpression();
        while (i < token.length) {
            String operator = token[i++];
            Expression right = binaryExpression();
            switch (operator) {
                case "AND":
                    expr = new BooleanExpression(expr, Operator.AND, right);
                    break;
                default:
                    expr = new BooleanExpression(expr, Operator.OR, right);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return expr;
    }

    private Expression binaryExpression() {
        String field = token[i++];
        String operator = token[i++];
        String value = token[i++];

        switch (operator) {
            case "EQ":
                return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.EQ, value);
            case "LT":
                return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.LT, value);
            case "GT":
                return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.GT, value);
            default:
                return new BinaryExpression(field, Operator.IN, value);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, QueryBuilder now has a state. You would use it as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Expression expr = QueryBuilder.parse("eid EQ 2 AND deptname EQ foo");
    System.out.println(expr);
}
```

UPDATE

I have defined these classes for testing:

```
abstract class Expression {
}

enum Operator {
    EQ, LT, GT, IN, AND, OR;
}

class BinaryExpression extends Expression {

    private final String field;
    private final Operator op;
    private final String value;

    BinaryExpression(String field, Operator op, String value) {
        this.field = field;
        this.op = op;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + field + " " + op + " " + value + ")";
    }
}

class BooleanExpression extends Expression {

    private final Expression left;
    private final Operator op;
    private final Expression right;

    BooleanExpression(Expression left, Operator op, Expression right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.op = op;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + left + " " + op + " " + right + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten the breaks, and the expression was built from right to left

Comment: :Thanks for your response, it worked for me. Can you please once explain the code i.e. right to left part?

Answer (score -2):

1. Check the input(String query) contains "AND".
2. If contains "AND", you split("AND")
3. Then, you call origin logic recursively put split item to input.
4. Last, you merge the result of each split input recursively.